# Why is this Jquery Selector not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select all the textboxes that have the class foo. Doing:

```
console.log( $("input .foo") );
```

doesn't work, however doing

```
console.log( $(".foo") );
```

works. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors. You want

```
$("input.foo");
```

What you had, `$("input .foo")` was selecting all descendants with class foo of any <input> element.

Answer (score 7):

The space is what's doing it. Should be `$("input.foo")`

The way you have it, it's looking for elements with class `foo` inside of an `input`.

Answer (score 2):

`input` can't have children -- just like an `img` element

Comment: They're not trying to reference the child of an `input` tag. They're trying to reference an `input` tag whose class is `foo`, but the syntax is incorrect (the extra space) - hence the problem.